# Magento : add custom php code into product description

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, custom, code

I wrote a php script that resizes jpeg images provided by external URL. The script works well on my server with a test page, but it seems that Magento doesn't allow custom php code into product description.

Is there any way to insert that piece of code into description ?

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$url_A = 'http:/...';
$url_B = 'http:/...';

$resizer_URL = 'http:/...';

echo '<a href="'.$url_A.'" target="_blank"><img class="scanA" src="'.$resizer_URL.'?url='.$url_A.'"/></a>
      <a href="'.$url_B.'" target="_blank"><img class="scanB" src="'.$resizer_URL.'?url='.$url_B.'"/></a>';

?>
```

The script code is:

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = $_GET['url'];

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio = $height / $width;

$new_width = 580; 
$new_height = $new_width * $ratio;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 75);

//
imagedestroy($image_p);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just edit your template if you wish to have this display for all products, if not you may have to filter what type of product, or if a custom attribute is set before running the code.

The file to edit would be (based on Magento 1.9 RWD theme)

`/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Obviously you have to change the path to your theme.

Then you could do something like so:

```
$url_A = $_product->getData('extra_url1');
$url_B = $_product->getData('extra_url2');

if($url_A != '' && $url_B != '') {
     ... do your code ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, i appreciate your suggestion but as you can see, the piece of php code (the first block) should be different for every product. In few words, for each product , this code should display two different images relatively to the self product.

Comment: So you simply add 2 attributes to the product - one for each url - then you check these exists and then do your code. So you enter the 2 URLs in your Product, if they exist, your code continues and outputs something .. else it does nothing. -> I've edited my answer

Comment: Your first answer has driven me on this way. But there is a problem, the resultant html code of php block can be displayed only before or after the long description. I can't integrate it into description body.

Anyway the solution you proposed could be the good one.

Comment: Glad I could be of help.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. If you find another solution let me know ! :D

Comment: I suppose you could use a placeholder, something magento doesn't strip from the description eg: `<<<XXX>>>` or similar, but maybe easier. Then replace the instance of it in the description with your variable (which holds your html output of your code). `$descr = $_product->getShortDescription(); $descr = str_replace("<<<XXX>>>", $myOutput, $descr);` and then go on and output the description - Just an idea, i've not tested this

Comment: It would be great if it could be done on product creation, during save.  
Do you think that is there a way to do that ? Maybe overriding core files!? 
The aim is to get the proper product description at save time, without call php script when item is displayed in frontend.

Comment: @tecjam Could you guide me how can i integrate Custom Feedback Form Code Into Magento -  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/244255/57334